# Should I design my database tables and relationships differently when I know my database files will reside on a SSD drive?

Tags: sql-server, data-modeling

We are planning to migrate all of our database disks to SSD.

Should I apply any changes to my data models to perform better on SSD?

Should I design my database tables and relationships differently when I know my database files will reside on a SSD drive?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of evil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I design my database tables and relationships differently when I know my database files will reside on a SSD drive?

No.